# Update a new row in the column every week

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm fairly new to google scripts and I'm having trouble updating a row then moving on to the next row in the column in google sheets... The code below updates the cell(A3), however when you run the code again it updates the same row. My hunch is the `A3` part... not too familiar with the google sheets syntax though... any help would be appreciated!

```
function getProfolioPrices() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A3').setValue('=GOOGLEFINANCE("TTWO", "price")');
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('C3').setValue('=GOOGLEFINANCE("TSLA", "price")');
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('E3').setValue('=GOOGLEFINANCE("AMZN", "price")');
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('G3').setValue('=GOOGLEFINANCE("NEP", "price")'); 
}
```

Comment: Sorry, was in my own world at that time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of script properties documented [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/). Script properties can be manually configured in `File > Project properties > Script properties`. You can use it to keep track of the next row you want to update, for example

```
function getProfolioPrices() {
  var activeSheet   = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var nextRowNumber = getNextRowNumber();

  activeSheet.getRange('A' + nextRowNumber).setValue('=GOOGLEFINANCE("TTWO", "price")');
  activeSheet.getRange('C' + nextRowNumber).setValue('=GOOGLEFINANCE("TSLA", "price")');
  activeSheet.getRange('E' + nextRowNumber).setValue('=GOOGLEFINANCE("AMZN", "price")');
  activeSheet.getRange('G' + nextRowNumber).setValue('=GOOGLEFINANCE("NEP", "price")'); 
}

function getNextRowNumber(){
  var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var nextRowCounter = scriptProperties.getProperty( 'nextRowCounter' );

  if ( isNaN( parseInt( nextRowCounter ) ) ) {
    nextRowCounter = 1; //Default to 1
  } else {
    nextRowCounter++;
  }

  scriptProperties.setProperty( 'nextRowCounter', nextRowCounter );

  return nextRowCounter;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, so much this exactly what I needed!